# Trying to create a user login with username and password

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp

I created a form with a submit button. I am also connected to the XAMPP database in the db.php file. I'm simply trying to enter a username and password into the fields and get redirected to another .php file. Every time I hit login with the username and password, nothing happens. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

```
<?php

  error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
  session_start();
  print_r($_POST['submit']);

  $dbCon = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'osticket') or die('can not connect');

  mysqli_select_db($dbCon, 'osticket');


 if ($_POST['submit']) {
   $username = trim($_POST['username']);
   $username = strip_tags($username);
   $username = htmlspecialchars($username);

   $password = trim($_POST['password']);
   $password = strip_tags($password);
   $password = htmlspecialchars($password);

   $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon,$username);
   $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon,$password);


   $sql = "SELECT * FROM ost_staff WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
   $query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql) or die (mysqli_connect_error($dbCon));


   if ($query) {
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $result["username"];
    $_SESSION['staff_id'] = $result["staff_id"];;

    header('Location: user.php');
   } else {
       echo "Incorrect username and password";
   }

}
 ?>


<form class="form-signin" method="post" action="ticket.php">
              <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign In</h2>
              <label for="inputUsername" class="sr-only">Username</label>
              <input type="text" id="inputUsername" class="form-control"         placeholder="Username" name="username" required autofocus>
              <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
              <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" required>
              <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
              <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
              </label>
              <input type="submit" value='Try it' name='submit'/>
      </form>
```

Comment: can you post your form as well

Comment: Just curious, why still check if the input is the same as the returned data? You had already used the inputs to find similar `username` and `password` to the db, it will either return 1 result or none at all.

Comment: i guess  you want to be hacked.

Comment: @CarlJan Just getting started in php :/ Trying to create a simple website for school that has username and pass login. Nothing too fancy.

Comment: Eric that's not what he is saying, he is saying after running the query you dont need your `if ($username == $dbUsername && $password == $dbPassword` as you already checked your input in your query, there is some thing wrong with your form that's why your code is not working, so post your form as well please

Comment: Is your passwords really in **pain-text**?? And you should learn how to use parameterized queries with placeholders.

Comment: @EricHo23 Ok, my advice is to remove that last `if` condition, it is redundant, use parameterized queries for `mysqli` instead of just inserting the variable to the query directly, and just check if the query had returned something, if true, save it to your `sessions` then redirect, if not then show an error.

Comment: @arif_suhail_123 thank you. Posted the form.

Comment: @EricHo23 And much better if you redirect back to the current page if there is no result returned instead of just echoing an error message. That way, users won't be bothered by that `"Form Resubmission"`  when they refresh your page

Comment: Is the PHP and html in the same page?

Comment: yes it is. PHP and html in the same file.Got rid of the second if statement. Also posted the form above. @CarlJan

Comment: before the closing form tag add `input type submit` if you are using pure php you have to use input type submit, other wise you are not sending any thing any where

Comment: What is the name of the file, is it `ticket.php`?

Comment: @arif_suhail_123 I already have a button that has a type="submit"

Comment: yes, the file name is ticket.php. I am connected to the database already. @CarlJan

Comment: `<input type= "submit" value='Try it' />` can you copy and paste this line, and make sure your file name is ticket.php as your form and code are on the same page

Comment: When I click on the button, it doesn't do anything. @arif_suhail_123

Comment: sorry wait `<input type= "submit" value='Try it'  name = 'submit'/>` as i forget the name field

Comment: error reporting would have thrown a few undefined index notices

Comment: @Fred-ii- stop helping people too much you are making them lazy

Comment: Looks like it did something. Duplicated my page contents. I got an error that says "Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ticket.php on line 14" @arif_suhail_123

Comment: yes i told you need to put input type submit, now wait, its mean your query is failing

Comment: do one thing, run your db.php in the browser, and second thing, make sure variable name for connection is $dbCon, in db.php

Comment: @arif_suhail_123 They're all yours.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you forget me again, you are the most humble guy on this site, other wise screw this site, i can imagine, some body is flagging my comment for moderator attention lol

Comment: Ran db.php in browser and worked fine, no errors. Retyped username and password in the fields, clicked try it and did nothing again. @arif_suhail_123

Comment: post your db.php as well, either some thing wrong in the file, or your query is failing, and it will depend which button you clicking on, if you click on input type submit button some thing will happen, you almost their any way

Comment: for the sake of trying remove the include line, and copy and paste the code from db.php instead, and chanage or `$query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);` to `$query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);die (mysqli_error($dbCon)); ` and see what happene

Comment: i made a mistake in the last code change it this `$query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($dbCon));`

Comment: Brings me to a blank page when I hit try it. I type in the username and wrong password and does the same thing - brings me to a blank page @arif_suhail_123

Comment: its really some thing stupid i am missing, and in my head your connection is failing that's what the error is saying, i really dont know i read it four or times i am not able to catch, i am really sorry, do one thing, and these are just guessing, as it going to the blank page, it only suggest two you never received the post request on ticket.php, so add this line print_r($_POST) to check what you are getting print_r($_POST['submit']) .............

Comment: .............to check weather you are getting submit input or not, and third change your connection lines to this, `$dbCon = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'osticket') or die('can not connect')`  and make sure you add your code in ticket.php and secon make sure you add them after session_start line not before this, read both the comment and also remember now it just guessing

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I really appreciate it. If you have any other suggestions, please let me know! And where do i add the print_r line?@arif_suhail_123

Comment: do it in free time, run this query in your localhost as well, `SELECT * FROM ost_staff WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'` change user name and password to right value and see what happened, if it does, just check the connection, sorry i try my level best, but i am literally confuse now

Comment: and add print_r line on the top, but if you have session_start() line in your code add after that, as session has to be on the top, and make sure you are adding it in ticket.php as your form action is ticket.php, hope its clear now

Comment: and one more thing, it may seem silly, but you are closing your form tag na?? as i cant see any form closing tag,

Answer (score 2):

There are a few mistakes or imperfection within your code.

First of all your input password field, doesn't have a name.
Just add name="password" to your input field:

```
<input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" required>
```

And also change the input "submit" to a button.

```
<button type="submit" value='Try it' name='submit'>test</button>
```

Also end the form with  (not quite sure if you already did, because it's cut off)

After that the code should work, but it isn't very beautiful. So here are just a few suggestions if you want to change it afterwards:

**Code change**

Change:

```
if ($query) {
 $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
 $staff_id = row[0];
 $dbUsername = row[3];
 $dbPassword = row[5];
}
if ($username == $dbUsername && $password == $dbPassword) {
 $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
 $_SESSION['staff_id'] = $staff_ID;
 header('Location: user.php');
} else {
 echo "Incorrect username and password";
}
```

To:

```
if ($query) {
 $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
 $_SESSION['username'] = $result["username"];
 $_SESSION['staff_id'] = $result["staff_id"];;

 header('Location: user.php');
} else {
    echo "Incorrect username and password";
}
```

Because if $query is true, then the check is already done just by looking into the database. And I changed the fetch_row to fetch_array, but that's just because I like it more in this way.

**Add Security**

To make your code a little more secure, here are also a few suggestions:

```
$username = trim($_POST['username']);
$username = strip_tags($username);
$username = htmlspecialchars($username);

$password = trim($_POST['password']);
$password = strip_tags($password);
$password = htmlspecialchars($password);

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon,$username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon,$password);
```

This is pretty **basic**, to prevent a few attacks.

Also maybe you want to make it more secure and hash the passwords (http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

There are also a lot of other things which you could change, but I want to keep it pretty simple. If you have any questions feel free to ask me.

Comment: Updated my php and added the form name. When I run the php it goes to a new page that says. "Try it." If I type an incorrect password it still goes to this page even when I echo "Incorrect username and password." Thanks. @Dead_Master

Comment: @EricHo23 So I have also a few changes https://jsfiddle.net/3o9s5p7q/2/ (look at the comments). If this doesn't work it's an error of the database, because I tried it on my pc and it worked ^^

Comment: hmmmm. Maybe its my database variables that I am using? Here is a gyazo of it. https://gyazo.com/f9790c8612b24f426ee4419fc40a7078

Comment: @EricHo23 Well there is something: Change $sql = "SELECT * FROM osticket WHERE username = '$username' AND password='$password'"; to $sql = "SELECT * FROM osticket WHERE username = '$username' AND passwd='$password'"; (https://jsfiddle.net/3o9s5p7q/4/)

Comment: That is weird. I just reinstalled osTicket so I got a new phpmyadmin database. What is it exactly doing for you when you sign in? Database is now called "eric" and table is called "ost_staff" where I am pulling the username and password from.

Comment: @EricHo23 Can you try to join this chat: https://hack.chat/?xd ? So we could exchange faster